# Oracle sql statement to store blob images with PHP

Tags: php, image, oracle, blob

Hi i have a question with regards to storing images into an oracle sql developer database through the use of PHP. I have already created a column in my table that accepts blob data types.

Take for instance i have a html form that will submit and store an image into the database

Html form

```
<form action ="image.php" method ="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type ="file" name ="pic" accept ="image/*"/>
<input type ="submit" value ="submit" name ="submit"/>
</form>
```

Image.php

```
$_file = $_FILES[pic];
$fileNmae = $_file['name'];
$imageData = file_get_contents($_file['tmp_name']);
$sql ="Insert sql statement here"
```

What do i have to write in the sql statement for it to work? I tried inserting the entire imageData into the database but i got returned with an ORA-0097(which basically means that the value that i'm trying to insert exceeds the limit of characters) exception.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18555/ch_twelve_blobs.htm#TDPPH185